# How to fix grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, gpt

My computer is an Intel NUC (bought this year) using UEFI successfully running Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu was installed Ok from a USB memory stick created by Startup Disk Creator from Ubuntu 16.04.4 iso image on my wife's Intel NUC Computer (bought a few months ago) running Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 (running on my NUC computer booted up from the Ubuntu 16.04.4 installer memory stick) onto a USB SSD, and that USB SSD boots into Ubuntu Ok. However, my Intel NUC computer no longer boots into Ubuntu: it stops at a Grub prompt. A memory stick containing the (bootable) Boot Repair hangs on the splash screen. So I followed some Terminal instructions as follows:
sudo fdisk -l -> sda with 3 partitions (i.e. the computer's SSD): same as on my wife's computer and sdb with 2 partitions (i.e. the Ubuntu Installer memory stick).
sudo blkid -> sda with 3 partitions: same as on my wife's computer:
sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda ->
Warning:...This GPT Partition Label contains no BIOS Boot Partition
Warning:...Can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists...
Error: Will not proceed with blocklists

Comment: Did you install to flash drive in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? If UEFI, the install to flash drive overwrote the UEFI ESP /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg with the UUID & partition info from flash drive. You still should be able to boot if flash drive plugged in. If you installed in BIOS mode, you have to switch UEFI to BIOS/CSM/Legacy and then back to UEFI for internal drive boot. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the BootInfo summary report.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: The install to flash drive (i.e. memory stick) was done on an Intel NUC computer. The BIOS on both Intel NUC computers uses UEFI.  How do I tell if it was done in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Similarly, the install to USB SSD was done using that flash drive. How do I switch from UEFI to BIOS/CSM/Legacy i.e. is it a BIOS parameter?  Link for Boot Summary is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/frrMHk2vbf/
PS SSD inside my NUC computer even though I haven't done anything else when I just tried to boot from USB SSD. I'm baffled!

Comment: From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI , Ubuntu on NUC's SSD is UEFI & EFI:
john@John:~$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"
Installed in UEFI mode
john@John:~$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" 
EFI boot on HDD
john@John:~$

Comment: Fast Boot & Secure Boot (in the BIOS) are both off.

Comment: I'm confused by your domestic <> Computer relationships. Whose computer are we trying to fix and can we focus on it? There is no need to fiddle about with fdisk on /dev/sda if your computer was already working. There was no need to create a new broken boot USB with boot-repair if you already had a working boot USB which you could have installed boot-repair on the fly to and fixed your UEFI boot. The rules  of **Ask Ubuntu** is to focus on one problem at a time. Forgetting about your wife for a second. Is your computer that was working broken now and are we trying to fix that?

Comment: The computer that I was trying to fix was mine. It would only boot into  a Grub prompt. The reason that I mentioned my wife's computer was to give info on its SDD (e.g. "sudo fdisk -l" & "sudo blkid" results). The computer that was broken (i.e. mine) is now fixed. But I don't understand how it was fixed.